# メールテンプレートを動的に変更したい？

Tags: html, google-apps-script

お世話になります。
GAS (Google Apps Script）で質問です。

- `MailApp.sendEmail`という関数でメールを発信しています。
- `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile`という関数でHTMLメールをテンプレートから組み立てています。
- HTML側では `<?=関数名(); ?>` という構文で、GASの関数を実行して、その戻り値でHTMLを書き換えています。

(GAS側：`Code.gs`)

```
function sendMail() {
  var recipient = "foo@example.com";
  var subject = "test mail subject";
  var variable = "こんにちは" + recipient + "さん"; // この内容をHTMLメールに入れ込みたい    

  var body = '';
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test').evaluate().getContent();

  var options = {
    htmlBody: htmlBody
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options);
}

function passData() {
  return "こんにちは、メールを受け取った人！"; // これでデータを渡せることは分かっているが。。
}
```

(HTML側: `test.html`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <?=passData(); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

上のコードで、関数`sendMail()`の中で、`test.html`の中身を変更するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
現状では、`passData()`を常に呼び出しているので「こんにちは、メールを受け取った人！」という文字列を埋め込むことは出来ていますが、`sendmail()`の中で指定した、「こんにちはfoo@example.comさん！」などの、さまざまな状況に応じたメッセージを指定したいのです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己回答です。
HTML側で`<?=関数();?>`ではなく`<?=変数>`と書き、GAS側でセットすればいいだけでした。

(GAS側：`Code.gs`)

```
function sendMail() {
  var recipient = "foo@example.com";
  var subject = "test mail subject";
  var variable = "こんにちは" + recipient + "さん"; // この内容をHTMLメールに入れ込みたい    

  var body = '';
  var htmlContent = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test');
  var html.variable = variable;
  var htmlBody = htmlContent.evaluate().getContent();

  var options = {
    htmlBody: htmlBody
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options);
}
```

(HTML側: `test.html`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <?= variable ?>
</body>

</html>
```

参考：https://productivityresearch.net/programing/13/